# JavaScript: using typeof to check if string

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a codecademy.com exercise where we use for-in statements to loop through an object and print hello in different languages by checking to see if the values of the properties in the languages object are strings using `typeof`

my check to see if the value is a string is not working. my loops giving me this result

```
english
french
notALanguage
spanish
```

The code

```
   var languages = {
        english: "Hello!",
        french: "Bonjour!",
        notALanguage: 4,
        spanish: "Hola!"
    };

    // print hello in the 3 different languages
    for(var hello in languages){
        var value = hello;
        if (typeof value === "string"){
        console.log(value); 
        }
    }
```

These are the instructions for the exercise

> Objects aren't so foreign if you really think about it!
>
> Remember you can figure out the type of a variable by using typeof
>   myVariable. Types we are concerned with for now are "object",
>   "string", and "number".
>
> Recall the for-in loop:
>
> for(var x in obj) { executeSomething();  }
>
> This will go through all the properties of obj one by one and assign
>   the property name to x on each run of the loop.
>
> Let's combine our knowledge of these two concepts.
>
> Examine the languages object. Three properties are strings, whereas
>   one is a number.
>
> Use a for-in loop to print out the three ways to say hello. In the
>   loop, you should check to see if the property value is a string so you
>   don't accidentally print a number.

Comment: it's possible to pose a question without using a question mark (?) and without using the typical syntax of a question. The OP showed what my problem was, and two people who answered (and all the people who upvoted) understood it clearly.

Comment: yes, you've given the code and the corresponding obvious output. It's a good idea to tell what *your* expectation was, since the code works perfectly valid.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That's because you're checking the `key` of the object. To check the actual value, you should be doing something like `object[key]`. Try this:

```
 var languages = {
        english: "Hello!",
        french: "Bonjour!",
        notALanguage: 4,
        spanish: "Hola!"
    };

// print hello in the 3 different languages
for(var hello in languages){
    var value = languages[hello];
    if (typeof value === "string"){
    console.log(value); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer: (use typeof and then the object name followed by the var in your for statement and test whether it is equal to "string")

```
var languages = {
    english: "Hello!",
    french: "Bonjour!",
    notALanguage: 4,
    spanish: "Hola!"
};

// print hello in the 3 different languages
for (var x in languages){
    if (typeof languages[x] === "string"){
        console.log(languages[x]);
    }
    else ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking keys of the object, not the value. It's usually a good practice to check against the constructor of an object to determine its type.

Something like this:

```
var languages = {
    english: "Hello!",
    french: "Bonjour!",
    notALanguage: 4,
    spanish: "Hola!"
};

for(i in languages) {

  if(languages[i].constructor === String) {
    console.log(languages[i])   
  };

};
```

Comment: Excellent. One advantage of comparing against an identifier instead of a string literal is that the latter won't throw an exception if there's a typo, whereas the former will. Still looks a bit clunky but the best option I found so far. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

"string" is not the same as String.  I've found one way to test typeof for string.

```
if (typeof something === typeof "test") ...
```

You can of course use "string" to compare to, but any actual String will do.

Comment: At first I didnt understand what you were saying, but now I see what you are doing.  Great thinking.  This way you can really be sure its a string value your finding.  For clarity you could improve it slightly and say:

    if (typeof something === typeof "string") ..

Answer (score 1):

this is the for in value to work for me

for(var x in languages){

```
if(typeof languages[x] === "string"){
    console.log(languages[x]);
} else }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below coding is also useful to perform only string value.By using variable to access the property list of abject after that by using it check the value is a NotANumber by using isNaN.The code given below is useful to you

```
var languages = {
english: "Hello!",
french: "Bonjour!",
notALanguage: 4,
spanish: "Hola!"
};

// print hello in the 3 different languages
for(a in languages)
{
if(isNaN(languages[a]))
console.log(languages[a]);
}
```