# Trying to print only string data

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to get the for-loop and if statement to just print out string data only.

var languages = {
        english: "Hello!",
        french: "Bonjour!",
        notALanguage: 4,
        spanish: "Hola!"
    };

```
// print hello in the 3 different languages
for (var x in languages) {
    if (typeof x === "string") {
        console.log(languages[x])
    }
};
```

Comment: You should tag your question with a programming  language.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is:

```
for (var x in languages) {
    if (typeof languages[x] === "string") {
        console.log(languages[x]);
    }
}
```

The way you've currently coded it will print out all the "keys" in the object since the keys are all "strings".

Answer (score 0):

In object literal terms, english,french,notALanguage, spanish are property. Properties are **strings** in JavaScript, although when defining the property name inside an object literal you may omit the string delimiters.

When looping through property names using a for...in, the property name is a **string** like

```
for (x in languages) {
    alert(typeof x);
    //-> "string"
}
```

You need like this

```
var languages = { english: "Hello!", french: "Bonjour!", notALanguage: 4, spanish: "Hola!" };

// print hello in the 3 different languages
 for (var x in languages) {
    //console.log(typeof x); //it will print 4 times because all keys are string
    if (typeof languages[x] === "string") {
        console.log(languages[x])
    }
 }
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/4hxgvr6q/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I actually found the same exact question I had from user :Leahcim posted with the correct answer from post user: Some Guy [JavaScript: using typeof to check if string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152691/javascript-using-typeof-to-check-if-string)

```
for (var hello in languages) {
    var value= languages[hello] 
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        console.log(value)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do and there is no unnecessary code in it.

```
for (let hello in languages) {
    if (typeof  languages[hello]  === "string") {
        console.log( languages[hello] )
    }
};
```